# Legend item hiding/showing other legend items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm combining spline and error bar charts. There are two separate error bar charts for min and max. Two error bar charts are needed because the min and max need to be shown/hidden with separate legend items. To achieve this I'm setting the first value for the min error bar to be the min value returned from an api call and I'm setting the max value to be the average value returned from the response. Conversely, I'm setting the average as the min value for the max error bar and the max value returned as the  max value. However, when I click the legend items the average item hides the min and max menu items and data, and the max menu item hide the min and max legend items. The only menu item that shows/hides it's associated data is the min item. How can I achieve proper legend item/data show/hide functionality? I tried the linkedTo property on the series but then the data isn't shown/hidden. [broken legend example](http://jsfiddle.net/14kw76o2/1/)

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Average',
    type: 'spline',
    color: 'transparent',
    marker: { fillColor: '#2B767F', symbol: 'circle'},
    data: [],
    showInLegend: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Max',
    type: 'errorbar',
    color: '#2B767F',
    data: [],
    showInLegend: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Min',
    type: 'errorbar',
    color: '#2B767F',
    data: [],
    showInLegend: true
  }]
```

Comment: It will be much easier to understand what you try to achieve if you set the fiddle with your actual data. Can you do this here http://jsfiddle.net/14kw76o2/?

Comment: Thanks, I added a fiddle in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Adding linkedTo: null, for the errorbar charts fixed the issue.